# Hibernate : include configuration files in WEB-INF in tests

Tags: java, hibernate, testing

I have a web app and i am trying to set up the config for the unit tests. I have the following structure

```
project
-src/main/java
-src/main/resources
-src/test/java
-src/test/resources
-src
  -main
    -webapp
      -WEB-INF
        -spring
  -test
    -spring
```

All my spring configuration files are stored in the `project\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring` directory. But the issue is that my test configuration files are stored in the `project\src\test\spring` directory.

For my tests i want to use some of the configuration files in the `project\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring` directory but i keep getting a file not found exception when i try access them.

Is there a way to keep my configuration files in the WEB-INF folder but still visible to my test configuration files?

Comment: I'm not a Hibernate expert, but I would say that you might want to consider  _mocking_ your database layer for the purpose of unit tests.

Comment: i am going to use an in memory database for testing as i want to stay away from mocking unless i have to or it makes sense to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you keep configurations in project\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring ?

You have to use:

- src/main/resources
- src/test/resources

respectively.

All files located in "src/main/resources" after maven build will be moved to {appRoot}/WEB-INF folder anyway.
Then from your tests you will see all files located in "src/main/resources"

Comment: I did not know these where moved to the WEB-INF folder anyways, thought you had to add them to the WEB-INF... thanks :)